# How to add user details against authentication User UID

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

## Problem

I have used flutterfire_ui for Authentication. During Signup the form doesn't asks for the details of the user i.e., name, address or phone number which i need to use for further purposes. How to use User UID from authentication and save the details of the user using that UID into the database.
After signing in the page routes to second page where I need to display the details of the currently signedIn user. Need to create more than one user and each time one of the user is Signed In, its details using currently signed In user's UID must be fetched and displayed. I am a Student of flutter and need your expert opions and help

## Code

```
import 'package:abcriderapp/signup.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ABC App',
      theme: ThemeData(


        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        ),
        outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
            textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            primary: Colors.white,
          )
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),


    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});



  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const HomePage();
          } else {
            return RegisterScreen(
              headerBuilder: (context, constraints, _) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    child: Image.network('https://firebase.flutter.dev/img/flutterfire_300x.png'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              subtitleBuilder: (context, action) => Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
              child: Text(action == AuthAction.signIn
              ? 'Welcome to ABC Delivery App! Please Login to the App'
              : 'Welcome to ABC Delivery App! Please SignUp to Enter App'
              ),
              ),
              footerBuilder: (context, _) => const Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text(
               'By Singing In you agree to our terms and conditions', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),

              ),
              ),
              providerConfigs: const [
                EmailProviderConfiguration(),
              ],

            );
          }
        }
        );
        }
```

I tried to create a table of users and copy pasting the UID manually from Authentication into the table but adding more users means doing more manual work. There must be a way to add the details of the currently Signed In using app.

Comment: What if I want to use the Document Id the document too in which we are adding UID or other details? I want to use that Document Id as primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to get the UID of the currentUser:

```html
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final uid = _auth.currentUser?.uid;
```

Comment: Okay once I got the uid, I can save it into the separate table. Let me check out this. By the way thank you for the information

Comment: Thank you for the help. It helped me a lot. I need to ask another thing can you help me to solve another problem? What if I want to use the Document Id of the collection too in which we are adding UID or other details?

Comment: nice to hear that.pls consider upvoting if you think it really helped you. And for your second question, you have to create a separate question for that, explaining briefly and concisely what you are trying to do and the output you are trying to achieve.